# Tkinter : Add columns with loop and manually in a Treeview : _tkinter.TclError: Column index out of bounds

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Hi a trying to make a Treeview with differents columns.
Seven of those columns are defined, and all of the others are created with a loop.
I know how to create columns with a loop, and i know how to create columns manualy, but i dont know how to do it on the same Treeview at the same time.

Here is my code :

```
# coding:utf-8
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, ttk


class Tableau(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("My Treeview")

        app_width = 1050
        app_height = 600

        screnn_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        screnn_heigth = self.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screnn_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
        y = (screnn_heigth / 2) - (app_height / 2)

        self.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
       # -------------------------------------------Configurer la page--------------------------------------------
        self.config(background="azure")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.focus_force()

        # Ajouter un style
        self.style = ttk.Style()

        # Choisir un theme
        self.style.theme_use('default')

        # Configure treeview
        self.style.configure("Treeview",
                             background="#D3D3D3",
                             foreground="black",
                             rowheight=25,
                             fieldbackground="#D3D3D3")

        # Changer couleur
        self.style.map('Treeview',
                       background=[('selected', '#347083')])

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack(pady=10)

        self.tree_scroll_horizontal = tk.Scrollbar(
            self.frame, orient='horizontal')
        self.tree_scroll_horizontal.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self.frame, xscrollcommand=self.tree_scroll_horizontal.set, columns=())
        self.tree.pack()

        self.tree_scroll_horizontal.config(command=self.tree.xview)
        for self.k in range(8, 50):
            print(self.k)
            self.tree["columns"] = ("ID", "Programme", "Date de début", "Date de fin","Effectif nécessaire", "Numéro OP", "Type Hélicoptère", list(range(8, 50)))

            self.tree.column(column="#0", width=0, stretch="no")
            self.tree.column(column="ID", anchor="center", width=140)
            self.tree.column(column="Programme", anchor="center", width=140)
            self.tree.column(column="Date de début", anchor="center", width=140)
            self.tree.column(column="Date de fin", anchor="center", width=140)
            self.tree.column(column="Effectif nécessaire", anchor="center", width=150)
            self.tree.column(column="Numéro OP", anchor="center", width=150)
            self.tree.column(column="Type Hélicoptère", anchor="center", width=150)
            self.tree.column(column=(str(self.k)), width=150, stretch=tk.NO)

            self.tree.heading(column="#0", text="", anchor="w")
            self.tree.heading(column="ID", text="ID", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Programme", text="Programme", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Date de début", text="Date de début", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Date de fin", text="Date de fin", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Effectif nécessaire",text="Effectif nécessaire", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Numéro OP", text="Numéro OP", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column="Type Hélicoptère",text="Type Hélicoptère", anchor="center")
            self.tree.heading(column= (str(self.k)),text=("Semaine " + str(self.k)), anchor=tk.W)

        self.tree.tag_configure('oddrow', background="white")
        self.tree.tag_configure('evenrow', background="lightblue")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Tableau()
    app.mainloop()
```

I got this error : _tkinter.TclError: Column index 8 out of bounds

That concern this line : line 68, in **init**
self.tree.column(column=(str(self.k)), width=150, stretch=tk.NO)

So how to create those columns at the same time, on the same treeview, without the same way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the following line:

```py
self.tree["columns"] = ("ID", "Programme", "Date de début", "Date de fin","Effectif nécessaire", "Numéro OP", "Type Hélicoptère", list(range(8, 50)))
```

will assign a tuple of 8 items (the last item is the list) to `self.tree["columns"]`.  So the index are 0 to 7, and exception raised when you try to access item in index 8.

The correct syntax is:

```py
self.tree["columns"] = ["ID", "Programme", "Date de début", "Date de fin", "Effectif nécessaire", "Numéro OP", "Type Hélicoptère"] + list(range(8, 50))
```

And this line should be put before the for loop (including some other lines):

```py
self.tree["columns"] = ["ID", "Programme", "Date de début", "Date de fin", "Effectif nécessaire", "Numéro OP", "Type Hélicoptère"] + list(range(8, 50))

self.tree.column(column="#0", width=0, stretch="no")
self.tree.column(column="ID", anchor="center", width=140)
self.tree.column(column="Programme", anchor="center", width=140)
self.tree.column(column="Date de début", anchor="center", width=140)
self.tree.column(column="Date de fin", anchor="center", width=140)
self.tree.column(column="Effectif nécessaire", anchor="center", width=150)
self.tree.column(column="Numéro OP", anchor="center", width=150)
self.tree.column(column="Type Hélicoptère", anchor="center", width=150)

self.tree.heading(column="#0", text="", anchor="w")
self.tree.heading(column="ID", text="ID", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Programme", text="Programme", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Date de début", text="Date de début", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Date de fin", text="Date de fin", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Effectif nécessaire",text="Effectif nécessaire", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Numéro OP", text="Numéro OP", anchor="center")
self.tree.heading(column="Type Hélicoptère",text="Type Hélicoptère", anchor="center")

for self.k in range(8, 50):
    print(self.k)
    self.tree.column(column=str(self.k), width=150, stretch=tk.NO)
    self.tree.heading(column=str(self.k), text="Semaine "+str(self.k), anchor=tk.W)
```

Comment: Can you guide me how can use excel import file with 100+ columns, manually setting heading is a lot of work and "for col in columns:
    treeview.heading("#0", text=col)" Returns blank column names